# How do I join 2 tables to a third one which contains the primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have 4 tables: the first is the client table, which has customer info, and client_id as an  auto-increment primary key.

The second and third are identical in structure: they are used to track attendance to 2 different therapy programs. They each have a primary key, and a client_id column to track the client. One of the fields contains units, which I want to sum.

The last table contains the therapists' info.

Basically I want to extract total amount of units for each client from the two attendance tables.

I have tried LEFT JOINS to no avail. I also tried a UNION ALL, but couldn't get it to sum the units.

This is how the tables look:

client:

```
+---------------------------------------+
| client_id |  f_name  | l_name | th_id |
|-----------|----------|--------|-------|
|     1     | sherlock | holmes |   1   |
|     2     | john     | watson |   4   |
|     3     | hercule  | poirot |   3   |
|     4     | jane     | marple |   2   |
+---------------------------------------+
```

therapist:

```
+--------------------------+
| th_id | f_name  | l_name |
|-------|---------|--------|
|   1   |  james  |  kirk  |
|   2   |  mr     |  spock |
|   3   |  bones  |  mccoy |
|   4   |  nyota  |  uhura |
+--------------------------+
```

attendance it:

```
+-------------------------------+
|   it_id   | client_id | units |
|-----------|-----------|-------|
|     1     |     1     |   4   |
|     2     |     1     |   4   |
|     3     |     1     |   0   |
|     4     |     1     |   2   |
|     5     |     4     |   0   |
|     6     |     4     |   4   |
|     7     |     4     |   0   |
|     8     |     4     |   2   |
+-------------------------------+
```

attendance psr:

```
+-------------------------------+
|   it_id   | client_id | units |
|-----------|-----------|-------|
|     1     |     1     |  16   |
|     2     |     1     |  16   |
|     3     |     1     |   0   |
|     4     |     1     |  12   |
|     5     |     4     |   0   |
|     6     |     4     |  14   |
|     7     |     4     |   8   |
|     8     |     4     |  10   |
+-------------------------------+
```

The result should look like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| client_id | total_units_it | total_units_psr |  therapist  |
|-----------|----------------|-----------------|-------------|
|     1     |       10       |       44        | james kirk  |
|     4     |        6       |       32        | mr spock    |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Please excuse the primitive representations, and please don't ask why the tables are designed  like that... ;-) Also, I obviously ignored many other fields which are not relevant to the question, such as dates, etc.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use join or you will create Cartesian product and duplicate the rows.

Instead you do a subquery:

```
 SELECT c.*
      , (SELECT SUM(units) FROM attendance_it a WHERE a.client_id = c.client_id ) as total_units_it 
      , (SELECT SUM(units) FROM attendance psr a WHERE a.client_id = c.client_id ) as total_units_psr 
      , t.*

 FROM client c
 JOIN therapist t 
   ON c.th_id = t.th_id
```

Answer (score 0):

use **group by client_id** to get the sum of each client. and no need to use join as you have already the ids in column.